# Как мне получить итератор begin и end?

Tags: c++

Пишу свой класс строк, решил добавить итераторы. Для хранения информации я НЕ использую string или же vector (У меня есть отдельный класс который хранит в себе ссылку на динамический массив). Как мне получить итераторы begin() и end() ??

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего вернуть указатели на первый символ (`begin`) и на несуществующий символ после последнего (`end`).

Если хочется чего-то более интересного (проверка на выход за границы?), то возвращать самодельный класс, сответствующий требованиями к итераторам ([1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) [2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator)).